# ASIFormDataRequest doesn't send post values

Tags: php, iphone, http-post

I try to send some values using ASIFormDataRequest. The problem is that even though the php script is executed no post data is received.

Here is what I do:

```
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setPostValue:@"Ben" forKey:@"first_name"];
[request setPostValue:@"Copsey" forKey:@"last_name"];
[request startSynchronous];
```

In order to check what the server receives I have the following php test script:

```
$handle = fopen("output.txt", "w");
fwrite($handle, count($_POST)."\n");
fwrite($handle, count($_GET)."\n");
fwrite($handle, count($_FILES)."\n");
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value)
{
 fwrite($handle, "POST $key=$value\n");
}
foreach ($_GET as $key => $value)
{
 fwrite($handle, "GET $key=$value\n");
}
fclose($handle);
```

The same script works with the following html fragment:

```
<FORM action="http://......."
       enctype="multipart/form-data"
       method="post">
   <P>
   What is your name? <INPUT type="text" name="submit-name"><BR>
   <INPUT type="submit" value="Send"> <INPUT type="reset">
 </FORM>
```

Because the html fragment works with the php script I suspect the php and server are not the problem.

But I don't have the slightest idea why ASIFormDataRequest doesn't work when called from my iPhone.

Could somebody please help me?

Regards,
Sascha

Comment: After some more testing I found out, that it is the server configuration. I haven't found out what causes the problem, but with a different server it works. I also found out, that on the faulty server the content-type header is missing and the request method is always GET (not POST how it should be). Both servers run xampp on windows xp. The faulty one has php 5.3.1 the working one php 5.2.5.

Comment: Ok, I've come to the conclusion, that my problem comes from the server configuration. Too bad, that I am kind of stuck with XAMPP on windows. Changing that isn't that easy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I finally managed to find the reason: the server was redirecting from site.com to www.site.com and losing the post values because of that. Without this redirect everything works fine. Hope this helps.

Comment: Great! Thanks for posting this.

Comment: Ahhhh YES! Finally an reason why my requests aren't working. I hadn't thought of my www redirects! You've saved me a bunch more time, thanks!

Comment: I'm redirecting from http to https and was sending the post request to http. This explains it!